# How can I use TCL linear algebra package for setting the elemnt of a matrix

Tags: tcl, linear-algebra

I am trying to use the ::math::linearalgebra:: package to do some simnple eigenvalue calculation for testing. The following code works and produces the desired result:

```
package require math
package require math::linearalgebra    
set Mat [::math::linearalgebra::mkMatrix 8 8 0.0]
puts "a single row is: [::math::linearalgebra::getrow $Mat 0 ] "
```

However when I try to chnage an element of matrix Mat I get an error:

```
set Mat [::math::linearalgebra::mkMatrix 8 8 0.0]
 ::math::linearalgebra::setelem $Mat 0 1 1.0]
puts "a single row is: [::math::linearalgebra::getrow $Mat 0 ] "
```

The error is:

> can't read "mat": no such variable
>       while executing "lset mat $row $col $newvalue"
>       (procedure "::math::linearalgebra::setelem" line 4)

How do I modify the elements of the created matrix if not with ::setelem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [manual](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/math/linalg.html#9), you have to give the *name* of the matrix. Thus you should do:

```
set Mat [::math::linearalgebra::mkMatrix 8 8 0.0]
::math::linearalgebra::setelem Mat 0 1 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I got a bit confused since the manual uses the 'matrix' keyword everywhere. however for example for the getrow procedure the Mat did not work only $Mat worked. I still have to figure out when to use which. For example when i pass a matrix with upvar 1 to a procedure I get the same error.

Comment: @Zolo When ot says name of matrix or vector, you shold not use `$`, when it says matrix or vector, then you need the `$`.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful! I think I got it now and things started working without error as well!